# How can we update Apache Solr Schema.xml?

Tags: schema, solr

We tried to modify the fields stored value to `true` but we are not able to get that value when executing the query.

Before:

```
<field name="CreatorId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

after:

```
<field name="CreatorId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

After saving the file we only restarted the IIS service.
Do we need to do more steps to update the Solr schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the CM side of things. If so, try restarting the "SDL Web Content Manager Search Indexer" (and "SDL Web Content Manager Search Host" just in case) service(s).

[image]

Comment: We tried restarting the SDL Web Content Manager Search Indexer and SDL Web Content Manager Search Host but still we are not able to receive the CreatorId value

Comment: Finally we were able to see the changes. we need to update the component in tridion which reindex the values in solr.

Comment: You can also "force" trigger an update using the Core Service's `ReIndex` method and pass in the id of the item.